# Show that if either N is even and M > 1 or M is even and N > 1, then the N × M grid is Hamiltonian.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

The grid in question is undirected.

The length of the Hamiltonian cycle should be even which should be possible in this grid since any N × M grid is bipartite. Besides this, I am not able to grasp any other insights which might help me to prove this.

What would be a good strategy to prove this?

Comment: Draw a couple of small examples, and I'm sure you'll see the pattern.

Comment: To prove that a particular graph is Hamiltonian, all you need to do is provide an example of a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: @Magma Okay, so if I define a Hamiltonian cycle starting (and ending) at the first node of the grid, then I would have proven that the grid is Hamiltonian. Can I then also conclude that no matter the starting point, there exists a Hamiltonian cycle in this grid?

Comment: @Bran Hamiltonian cycles are cycles, they don't have a starting or ending point.